# whats wrong am i doing please to use scanner.usedelimiter(".")

Tags: java, file-io

this is first time i am writing please excuse to me if some thing wrong i typed:-

so question is when is use `scan.delimeter(".")` to read the file then it showing error of `missMatchException` but when i use `scan.delimiter(",")` then it works fine why is it happening please someone explain me

here is some code what use to read the file:-

```
    Scanner scanner = null;
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("locations.txt"));
            scanner.useDelimiter(".");
            System.out.println(scanner.hasNextLine());
            while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                int loc = scanner.nextInt();
                scanner.skip(scanner.delimiter());
                String description = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Imported loc: " + loc + ": " + description);
                Map<String, Integer> tempExit = new HashMap<>();
                locations.put(loc, new Location(loc, description, tempExit));
            }

        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(scanner != null) {
                scanner.close();
            }
        }
```

file location.txt contains

```
0.You are sitting in front of a computer learning Java
1.You are standing at the end of a road before a small brick building
```

error:

```
 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at com.company.Locations.<clinit>(Locations.java:47)
Exception in thread "main"
```

the above code creates problem but if I replace from "." to ","  in code at delimiter() and in location.txt also then it works fine

Comment: Supply test cases or any additional resources such as exceptions etc,.

Comment: You should try "\." in useDelimeter(). It's looking for a pattern rather than a character, and "." matches any single character.

Comment: @NomadMaker Its not taking "\." in useDelimiter().its showing "**Illegal escape character in string literal**"

Comment: Sorry, you have to use "\\.". The first \ escapes the second \, so that "\." is sent to the method.